# How to bundle the war with different configuration in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

1. i need to change multiple xml file while build a war  using maven like below example
2. I am able to do the required change in the target folder. But It is not copied in to the war file

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
       <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.3</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>replace</goal>
               </goals>
               <id>dse xml replacer</id>
               <configuration>
               <file>
                   ${project.artifactId}/target/${project.artifactId}-${version}/WEB-INF/example.xml
               </file>
               <replacements>
                   <replacement>
                       <token>reloadingEnabled=".*"</token>
                       <value>reloadingEnabled="false"</value>
                   </replacement>
               </replacements>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </plugin>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the **maven-war-plugin**, like:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>resource2</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

More info https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Comment: This modified file ( /WEB-INF/example.xml) should go in to the war. I don't understand how this maven-resources-plugin will do.

Comment: I'd interpreted your question wrong... I've updated my answer, for copying to the inside of a war (including the link)